# Unable to get entered number from Input type number tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a Calculator app made with using Javascript . But in starting when i tried to get entered number in input type number tag in alert box , i am keep getting NaN.

My HTML code:

```
 <div>
        <label for="forms_bill" class="forms_label">Bill</label><br>

        <div class="forms_icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="17">
            <path fill="#9EBBBD"
              d="M6.016 16.328v-1.464c1.232-.08 2.22-.444 2.964-1.092.744-.648 1.116-1.508 1.116-2.58v-.144c0-.992-.348-1.772-1.044-2.34-.696-.568-1.708-.932-3.036-1.092V4.184c.56.144 1.012.4 1.356.768.344.368.516.816.516 1.344v.288h1.824v-.432c0-.448-.088-.876-.264-1.284a3.783 3.783 0 00-.744-1.116A4.251 4.251 0 007.54 2.9a5.324 5.324 0 00-1.524-.492V.872H4.288V2.36a5.532 5.532 0 00-1.416.324c-.448.168-.84.392-1.176.672-.336.28-.604.616-.804 1.008-.2.392-.3.844-.3 1.356v.144c0 .96.316 1.708.948 2.244.632.536 1.548.884 2.748 1.044v3.912c-.704-.16-1.248-.472-1.632-.936-.384-.464-.576-1.08-.576-1.848v-.288H.256v.576c0 .464.08.924.24 1.38.16.456.404.88.732 1.272.328.392.744.728 1.248 1.008s1.108.476 1.812.588v1.512h1.728zM4.288 7.424c-.688-.128-1.164-.332-1.428-.612-.264-.28-.396-.644-.396-1.092 0-.464.176-.832.528-1.104.352-.272.784-.448 1.296-.528v3.336zm1.728 5.712V9.344c.768.128 1.328.328 1.68.6.352.272.528.688.528 1.248 0 .544-.196.984-.588 1.32-.392.336-.932.544-1.62.624z" />
          </svg>
          <input type="number" id="bill_value" class="forms_same forms_bill" placeholder="0" onfocusout="sbill()">
          <br>
        </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
let bill = document.getElementById('bill_value').value;
let nbill = parseInt(bill);

function sbill() {
  alert(nbill);
}
```

I tried to get value by many other methods like by className , tagName , getAttribute , etc i used different methods for calling function but none of these works. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you placed `bill` and `nbill` outside of the function body, they were only evaluated once when the page was first loaded.

Move them inside the function body so that they are re-evaluated every time the function is called.

**Like this:**

```js
function sbill() {
  let bill = document.getElementById('bill_value').value;
  let nbill = parseInt(bill);
  alert(nbill)
}
```

**Full code:**

```js
function sbill() {
  let bill = document.getElementById('bill_value').value;
  let nbill = parseInt(bill);
  alert(nbill)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="forms_bill" class="forms_label">Bill</label><br />

    <div class="forms_icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="17">
            <path
                fill="#9EBBBD"
                d="M6.016 16.328v-1.464c1.232-.08 2.22-.444 2.964-1.092.744-.648 1.116-1.508 1.116-2.58v-.144c0-.992-.348-1.772-1.044-2.34-.696-.568-1.708-.932-3.036-1.092V4.184c.56.144 1.012.4 1.356.768.344.368.516.816.516 1.344v.288h1.824v-.432c0-.448-.088-.876-.264-1.284a3.783 3.783 0 00-.744-1.116A4.251 4.251 0 007.54 2.9a5.324 5.324 0 00-1.524-.492V.872H4.288V2.36a5.532 5.532 0 00-1.416.324c-.448.168-.84.392-1.176.672-.336.28-.604.616-.804 1.008-.2.392-.3.844-.3 1.356v.144c0 .96.316 1.708.948 2.244.632.536 1.548.884 2.748 1.044v3.912c-.704-.16-1.248-.472-1.632-.936-.384-.464-.576-1.08-.576-1.848v-.288H.256v.576c0 .464.08.924.24 1.38.16.456.404.88.732 1.272.328.392.744.728 1.248 1.008s1.108.476 1.812.588v1.512h1.728zM4.288 7.424c-.688-.128-1.164-.332-1.428-.612-.264-.28-.396-.644-.396-1.092 0-.464.176-.832.528-1.104.352-.272.784-.448 1.296-.528v3.336zm1.728 5.712V9.344c.768.128 1.328.328 1.68.6.352.272.528.688.528 1.248 0 .544-.196.984-.588 1.32-.392.336-.932.544-1.62.624z"
            />
        </svg>
        <input type="number" id="bill_value" class="forms_same forms_bill" placeholder="0" onfocusout="sbill()" />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

write Your Variables inside of your function !

```
function sbill() {
        let bill = document.getElementById('bill_value').value;
        let nbill = parseInt(bill);
        alert(nbill);
    }
```

Observe scope :)